# IMAP 4 Client Authentication issue

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have a windows service which is scheduled to run below method every 5minutes and read emails and process the attachement i.e. convert tiff to pdf and update the database by reading the QR code of attachement, I have observed a issue recently the Service got hanged i.e. I could not stop it from services.msc and have to kill it from task manager although it worked well for last 2months without issue.

Upon investigating the log I observed the log entry was "IMAP 4 Client Authentication Started"
and it never reached "IMAP 4 Client Authentication Done" although as it is schedule to call this method every 5minutes I could see the logs from there on call to the below method

"call to processEmail for user Dept1 "

"call to processEmail for user Dept2 "

son on........

```
private readonly object _myLock = new object();

public void start()
{
      // all the belwo variable read from config file...
    Log.WriteLog("call to processEmail for user " + username);
     ProcessEmail(host, username, password, connPort);
     Log.WriteLog("Service Completed reading for user " + username);


}

public void ProcessEmail(string host, string username, string password, int connPort)
{
            Monitor.Enter(_myLock); //_myLock defined at class level
            Log.WriteLog("IMAP 4 Client Authentication Started");
            using (Imap4Client imap = new Imap4Client())
            {
                try
                {
                    imap.ConnectSsl(host, connPort);          // port 993 for SSL Connect 
                    imap.Login(username, password);
                    imap.Command("capability");
                    Log.WriteLog("IMAP 4 Client Authentication Done");

                    //fllowed by reading email from Inbox and junk emails.      

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Log.WriteLog(ex.Message);
                }
                finally
                {
                    Monitor.Exit(_myLock);
                }

            }
}
```

My concern is if due to some reason  imap.Login(username, password) fails, why the code block holds the lock by not allowing other instances to login as in finally block I am releasing the lock Monitor.Exit(_myLock), and I don't even see the exception recorded in log file, does imap.Login(username, password) trying to connect for ever to login, any suggestion/help on this would be of great help.

Again - this issue occurred today and from the log I could see this time

Message: Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

followed by -
               **Service Completed reading for user " + username**

and then again sequentially...
**call to processEmail for user  Dept1 **
**call to processEmail for user  Dept2 **

Is this issue has something to do with Activeup.Net.Imap4 client or could itbe Deadlock issue as I don't see anything that would cause deadlock..

Comment: You can debug your service as a console application if you host it in [topshelf](http://topshelf-project.com/)

Comment: This doesn't happen in Dev it's on prod once in 2months I come across this issue and the variable lock object is declared as private readonly object _myLock = new object();

Comment: Does this happen on your side or on the customers side ? Maybe they changed the connect to use `starttls`

Comment: This happen on my side i.e. on application server as the wndows service is installed on application server.

Comment: I would at least try to move `Monitor.Exit()` after the using block. Did you check the eventlog of the application server ?

Comment: Appreciate your comment but I suppose the same it would do in finally block as well or will it make difference. Will check the evenlog but as already the catch block was there was under the impression it has to log in the log file.

Comment: I verified eventlog but nothing found which would give a hint on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

After looking into Imap4 I couldn't find much to do in connectssl,Login and command method as to why it's going unresponsive and causing deadlock I have plan to implement the below solution for the issue -

```
        Log.WriteLog("IMAP 4 Client Authentication Started");
        using (Imap4Client imap = new Imap4Client())
        {
            try
            {
                imap.ConnectSsl(host, connPort);          // port 993 for SSL Connect 
                imap.Login(username, password);
                imap.Command("capability");
                Log.WriteLog("IMAP 4 Client Authentication Done");

                 //fllowed by reading email from Inbox and junk emails.  
                 try
                {
                    Monitor.Enter(_myLock);
                    ReadEmails(imap, "inbox");
                    LogHelper.WriteLogEntry("Retrieving junk e-mail unread emails started");
                    ReadEmails(imap, "junk");

                }catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    Log.WriteLog(ex.Message);
                }
                finally
                {
                    Monitor.Exit(_myLock);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.WriteLog(ex.Message);
            }

        }
```

Please advice if any better solution.